# Jenkins badge dynamic update with React/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jenkins, badge

I'm building a dashboard listing all our different projects, environments and pipelines. I'm using Jenkin's badges to show the status of the pipelines.

I would like to update automtically these badges to the current status without having to refresh the page manually, like every 10 seconds.
I would also like to avoid having to just refesh the whole page, but just the component containing the image, or just the image object itself.

How could I achieve that? I've already tried using `setInterval` on my components containing Jenkins badges but it doesn't update the badge image at all (no request done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in fact, using setInterval that updates a random hook AND appening random values to the URL of the img does work.

I only used one solution at a time but using both work like a charm